# Visual Studio 2010: Generating Number Increments Using For-Next Loop Structure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, for-loop

I am creating a program where the user inputs 2 numbers, and depending on whether or not the difference is positive or negative (First Number - Second Number), the program will output lines of numbers in increments of 2 between them.

For example, if my first number was 8 and my second number was 0, the display would be: 2 4 6 8

This is my code:

```
    Private Sub DualInput(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDualInput.Click
    'Displays two numbers in increments or decrements of 2. 
    Num3 = InputBox("Enter your first number.", "First Number")
    Num4 = InputBox("Enter your second number.", "Second Number")
    Dim increment As Integer
    'Positive Difference
    If (Num3 - Num4) > 0 Then
        For increment = Num3 To Num4 Step 2
            lblAnsDual.Text += increment
        Next increment
        'Negative Difference
    ElseIf (Num3 - Num4) < 0 Then
        For increment = Num4 To Num3 Step -2
            lblAnsDual.Text += increment
        Next increment
        'Zero
    Else : MsgBox("The difference cannot be zero!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If
    lblAnsDual.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I get no errors, however, the output only returns the text from the label (which I set by default to "Answer")

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I fixed it myself with this code

```
Private Sub DualInput(sender As   System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDualInput.Click
    lblAnsDual.Visible = True
    'Displays two numbers in increments or decrements of 2. 
    Num3 = InputBox("Enter your first number.", "First Number")
    Num4 = InputBox("Enter your second number.", "Second Number")
    Dim increment As Integer
    'Positive Difference
    If Num3 > Num4 Then
        For increment = Num3 To Num4 Step -2
            lblAnsDual.Text += Str(increment)
        Next increment
        'Negative Difference
    ElseIf Num3 < Num4 Then
        For increment = Num3 To Num4 Step 2
            lblAnsDual.Text += Str(increment)
        Next increment
        'Zero
    Else : MsgBox("The difference cannot be zero!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If
```